# Не могу остановить docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть несколько докер контейнеров, которые были запущены через `docker-compose`.

Я делаю `docker ps`. Выбираю id контейнеров. Затем, говорю

docker kill   ...

Но спустя какое-то время контейнеры переподнимаются. В чём проблема?

Comment: Кубернетис или еще какая-то система оркестрации работает и поднимает их на место?

Comment: а у вас в `docker-compose` не стоит `restart: always`?

Comment: @gbg кстати, да, ща swarm погляжу.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten убирал ручками